# 3d scatter plot with histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I want to plot histograms next to the axis of my 3d plot (something like the image but in 3d)
[image]

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)
z = np.random.randn(1000)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, s = 1, color='black')
```

Looking at the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-hist-py) I don't know how to extrapolate to 3d axes.

I have a 3d plot such as the one below and histograms for each axis that I want to plot next to it.

[image]

Comment: you should use `plotly` and `cufflinks` to create 3d plots.

Comment: Hey I was willing to help you so could you please tell me that what issue are you actually facing and what help you need?

Comment: I would recommend a scatter-matrix to visualise your data

Answer (score 0):

for such a plot in figure use `seaborn.jointplot`

you should use `plotly` and `cufflinks` to create 3d plots

Comment: As far as I understand seaborn.jointplot is also only for 2d plots. I've edit to post and hope its clearer now